# WooCommerce IPN Notification

Tags: wordpress, perl, paypal, woocommerce

I need some help typing to figure out what im doing wrong.

My site is setup to manage orders using WooCommerce. the site is a public site, but my Perl Script needs to be implemented as im testing a few things out and displaying some messages. The public site is called 'publicwebsite.com'. But the other site im displaying all this information and proccess it is called 'mywebsite.com'

I have setup my API credentials and setup my IPN for paypal payment. To direct the IPN to my website i have gone into the 'My Selling Tools' on the sandbox side of Paypal, and set the IPN to http://mywebsite.com/test_pl.html

when i place and order, somehow the IPN is not being directed to the URL. I went to the IPN tabe again on the Paypal side, and clicked on history, and i see that the 'Notification URL' is still set to http://publicwebsite.com/WC_Gateway_Paypal, whereas it should have been http://mywebsite.com/test_pl.html.

I cannot seem to find the place where i can change the preferences such that Woocommerce pushes the information onto the site.

Please Help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I'm not familiar with Woocommerce in particular, but an individual transaction can set a different IPN address; presumably Woocommerce is doing so. It is a little odd that you want to use test_pl.html as an IPN; is that in fact a script that is looking for POST data?

Comment: its is a webpage, that tests the IPN and the transaction by running a status.pl script, and then based on return values produces a webpage. The problem is woocommerce overrides the custom set notification somehow

Answer (score 1):

WooCommerce will set the IPN location of each transaction so that it can be notified when an item is paid for and continue its process.

Not knowing your data flow, I would suggest looking into woocommerce available hooks and hook into the IPN notification and then send the data (and user) to your perl script.

This way you satisfy WooCommerce's condition that it needs to know about payments, and you satisfy your need to have your perl script called so that it can do additional processing.

Comment: I want to emphasize that, woocommerce does set it up for you. There are lots of tutorials out there that state that you have to setup your ipn url in paypal. That is not the case, ipn works out of the box, at least for me. So Adam is correct about woocommerce setting it up on every transaction!

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution is to update your IPN settings in your PayPal Account. If you have a standard PayPal account here are the instructions directly from PayPal Documentation:

1. Go to the PayPal website and log in to your account.
2. Click Profile at the top of the page.
3. Click My selling tools.
4. Click Update beside "Instant payment notifications" in the "Getting paid and managing risk" section.
5. Enter the notification URL and select "Receive IPN messages."
6. Click Save.

Just in case you need it below is the PayPal Instant Payment Notification Guide. It includes an IPN simulator.

[PayPal Instant Payment Notification Integration Information](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/gs_IPN/)